# How to display the red tick at the bottom outside the border?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

Here is my source code and screenshot of the sample app I'm doing. My only concern is how can I show the red tick outside the border at the bottom part?

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Chart {
        ForEach(chartData, id: \.id) { item in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Beat", item.beat),
                y: .value("Value", item.value)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(item.type.color.opacity(lineVisibility[item.type]!))
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Plot", item.type))
            .lineStyle(.init(lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
    .border(.black, width: 2)
    .chartLegend(.hidden)
    .chartYAxis(.hidden)
    .chartXAxis {
        AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: numberOfBeats, roundLowerBound: true, roundUpperBound: true)) { _ in
            AxisGridLine(stroke: .init(lineWidth: 1)).foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
            AxisTick(centered: true, length: 20, stroke: .init(lineWidth: 1))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
        }
    }
    .padding(.trailing, 15)
    
    HStack {
        Text("0 beat")
            .padding(.leading, -15)
        Spacer()
        Text("\(numberOfBeats) beat")
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: GENERAL_WIDTH * 2)
.padding(.trailing, 10)
```

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using an `offset`, such as:

```
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: numberOfBeats, roundLowerBound: true, roundUpperBound: true)) { _ in
        AxisGridLine(stroke: .init(lineWidth: 1)).foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
        AxisTick(centered: true, length: 20, stroke: .init(lineWidth: 1))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
        AxisTick(centered: true, length: 20, stroke: .init(lineWidth: 1))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            .offset(y: 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: did my answer not worked or helped you?